# How can i debug my app with my private key

Tags: android

Can anybody explain me how can i publish my app on android market or how can i debug my app with the private key.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The link below provides all the information you need for signing and publishing your Android application.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

In regards to debugging, you can either use the Android emulator with Eclipse and the Android Plug-in or use enable your device by selecting Settings > Applications > Allow USB Debugging (on the device), then choosing the device as the target when compiling.